# extern linking problems in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll, hyperlink, extern

I have two libs that share a extern variable.
In libA I have the variable declared in the header as such:

```
extern int Gbl;
```

then I define it again in the source as:

```
int Gbl;
```

next then I set Gbl=1;

in libB, I include libA's header file. And printf Gbl, expecting to get 1 here.

though unfortunately i can't even compile this since I get the error:

```
undefined symbol '_Gbl' referenced in ....
```

I was told that this is a linking error, but I'm not sure what to do from here

Comment: It is a linker error, you need to link libA as well as libB.  Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure how to get to that. I'm using the visual studios compiler through labwindows

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels: http://sine.ni.com/psp/app/doc/p/id/psp-272

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the libB with libA included. This is done by adding -llibA to the compile line. If you don't have library options set correctly, you need to add -lpath_to_library

Comment: i just tried the equivalent of that in labwindows and it still gave me the same error